# Are these lines on my granite an issue?

Tags: kitchen-counters

I noticed these lines in my countertop when the sun was shining just right.  I don’t know how long how they have been here, but just noticed.

They appear to be on the surface and don’t match up with the underlining granite features.  Is this indicative of needing resealing or some other issue I need to address?[image]

Comment: Run a finger tip over them.  If scratches, should be able to feel them.  If surface is smooth, then just weird lines in the granite.